# The co-ordinates of trapezium ABCD are A(3,5), B(-5,4) and C(1,-5). AD is parallel to BC and ADC is 90 degrees..

Tags: geometry

Can you help me with this, I’m struggling with finding the right equation for this problem.

Specifically, I need to find the co-ordinates of D.

Comment: Hint. Write $\overrightarrow{AD}=\alpha\overrightarrow{BC}$ and use $\overrightarrow{AD}\cdot\overrightarrow{DC}=0$ to find $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a direct formula, or at least this is irrelevant if you use the ideas in the image. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the line $BC$ is:
$$a=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{4-(-5)}{-5-1}=-\frac32.$$
Since $AD||BC$, the slope of the line $AD$ is also $-\frac32$. The equation of the line $AD$ must pass through the point $A(3,5)$:
$$y_{AD}=-\frac32x+\frac{19}{2}.$$
Since $ADC=90^\circ$, it implies $CD\perp AD$, hence the line $CD$ has the slope $\frac23$ and it passes through the point $C(1,-5)$:
$$y_{CD}=\frac23x-\frac{17}{3}.$$
Finally, the intersection of the lines $AD$ and $CD$ is the point $D$:
$$\begin{cases}y_{AD}=-\frac32x+\frac{19}{2}\\ y_{CD}=\frac23x-\frac{17}{3}\end{cases} \Rightarrow D(x,y)=D(7,-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x, y)$ be the coordinates of point $D$.

Since $\overline{AD} \parallel \overline{BC}$, the slope of $\overline{AD}$ is equal to that of $\overline{BC}$.  Since,
\begin{align*}
m_{\overline{AD}} & = \frac{y - 5}{x - 3}\\
m_{\overline{BC}} & = \frac{-5 - 4}{1 - (-5)} = \frac{-9}{6} = -\frac{3}{2}
\end{align*} 
we obtain 
$$\frac{y - 5}{x - 3} = -\frac{3}{2} \tag{1}$$
Since $m\angle ADC = 90^\circ$, $\overline{AD} \perp \overline{CD}$.  Since 
$$m_{\overline{AD}} = m_{\overline{BC}} = -\frac{3}{2}$$
and the slopes of nonvertical perpendicular lines are negative reciprocals,
$$m_{\overline{CD}} = \frac{2}{3}$$
Since the slope of $\overline{CD}$ is 
$$m_{\overline{CD}} = \frac{y - (-5)}{x - 1} = \frac{y + 5 }{x - 1}$$
Equating the two results for the slope of $\overline{CD}$ yields
$$\frac{y + 5}{x - 1} = \frac{2}{3} \tag{2}$$
You can determine the coordinates of point $D$ by solving the system of equations 1 and 2.